# How can I add content into a CKeditor5 by clicking on an outside element

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have a few buttons outside of the Ckeditor on my page, and I want to click on them and add content to the Ckeditor5.

By clicking on the buttons, I make an ajax call to retrieve the content from the server, but I'm having trouble inserting it. This is my code right now:

```
success: function (data) {
            
            ClassicEditor
            
            .create( document.querySelector( '.ckeditor' ), {
                language: 'he',
            } )
            .then( editor => {
                editor.model.change( writer => {
                    const insertPosition = editor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition();
                    writer.insertText(data, insertPosition );
                } );
            } )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
            } );
            
        }
```

But this code duplicates my editor, and I don't know how to get the "editor" object without using ".create". can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try executing the input command

```
editor.execute('input','sample text');
```